# Port of a util class as project on resume

Tags: resume

Greeting everyone,
I am actually a college student and I recently started to rewrite in C++ the Java Scanner utility class and wanted to know if it will be worth it as I initially planned to put it on my resume along with other small projects to increase my chances to get an internship.
Thank you.

Comment: Was this a homework project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that this is indeed the most perfect port of the class one could ever make. What does it tell me about you?

Good:

- You have a basic proficiency in C++ and you know at least enough Java to understand the API.
- You know your way around string manipulations
- You can code to precise specifications

Bad:

- You are solving problems which don't actually need to be solved. Instead of coming up with novel new project ideas which have actual value, you are reinventing the wheel and repeat solutions to problems which are already solved.
- You lack the understanding of C++ to understand that practices which work well in Java do not necessarily work just as well in C++. That's why you built a compatibility layer even though C++ already has more appropriate native ways to solve the problems your class solves. In an interview I would probe how well you know these native techniques and why you believe that your class is superior. (by the way: this is common behavior of people who switch to a new technology. Instead of embracing its philosophy they try to hammer it into working the way they are used to)
- You lack the creativity to come up with your own specifications and come up with ways how existing technology could be improved. If I interview you, I would certainly ask if there is anything you dislike about the API of java.util.Scanner and how you would have solved it differently. An interesting answer to this might save you.

But you are applying just for an internship, not a senior developer position, so I might look beyond those "bad" points and interview you anyway (depending on the competition, of course).

Comment: I'm assuming that OP rewrote these things as an educational exercise to test his knowledge of both languages and see how concepts from one language translate to the other. The "bad" points are only relevant if he was actually using his Scanner class in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java person so had to google the code, but found this in about 30 seconds:

[How to implement Java “Scanner” in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821598/how-to-implement-java-scanner-in-c)

From looks there are questions on WHY you'd need this as it looks there are trivial ways of achieving similar in c++.

As a result I wouldn't suggest this is something worth drawing attention to on a resume, you want to highlight achievements and key facts, not a homework assignment.